# Xbee traffic/bandwidth limitations for a real-time-ish application

Tags: sensor, wireless, xbee

I am planning on making a wireless sensor network with 4 Xbees going to 1 Coordinator. I want each of the sensor nodes to transmit continuously at ~5Hz.

Is this feasible with Xbees? What sort of traffic limitations does the protocol have in regards to collisions, dropped packets, latency, etc.?

Comment: "transmit continuously at 5Hz" is a bit confusing. Do you mean they need to send one message 5 times a second?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that each sensor is sampling and sending data to the coordinator at 5hz.

Comment: How much data is being sent? There is not nearly enough information here. If you are getting 1Gb of data this is really easy to answer, if you are getting 1 byte, juts as easy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much data is actually sent every 200 ms, this can certainly be feasible for a 4to1 network.  I've done this with 8to1 networks with a 10 Hz update rate, sending about 20 bytes every time.  It works like a charm.  The xbees come in different flavors, but in general you can get receipt acks at the xbee level (if in API mode), or you can simply implement your own at the application level.  Depending on the configuration, the xbees will attempt a set amount of retries on their own.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using anything but API mode.  Using application-level acknowledgment may be better than xbee acks if one needs to send data in response to a message, but in transparent mode there's no guarantee that one won't receive part of one message combined with part of another, so as to erroneously resemble a whole message.